# UI question: Designing a combobox to be one element high

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dom-events

**This is a UI question, dealing with HTML and Javascript, to see how to get the functionality I want without confusing the user**

I have a table below that has a select box as the first cell in my table.

This application has no submit button. You change the select box, the database is updated, you change something in an input box the database is updated.

Everything is based on the `onchange` event in Javascript.

My problem is that the user will need to be able to add items to the select box, as it is not an exclusive list.  But, I want to keep the UI consistent, so I want to allow the user to just type in the select box, hence the need for a combo box.

But, I don't want a combobox that is two elements stacked, as that will make each cell higher than it needs to be.

So, the other option is to use a `onkeydown` event and if they use characters from ASCII 32-97 or so (only English words), then that will go into an input box, so, when they click away, the select box has a new item in it.

But, in order to do this, I will need to hide/unhide two elements sharing the same place, an input box and a select box, both in the first column of the table.  The shifting of the elements will be confusing.

--> QUESTION 1: So, how can I make this less distracting to the user?  <--

--> QUESTION 2: Is there another way to have an editable select box that may be less distracting in HTML? <--

**This is a UI question, the table below is because it seems to be important to some people**

The table is here purely for illustrative purposes.

```
<table border="1" bgcolor="#ffcc99" width="90%">
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="SourceFunds*SourceID*SourceID^SourceNumber*1113^1">
<option value="1119">Capital Maintenance</option>
<option value="1063">Waterworks Fund</option>
<option value="1114">Waterworks Fund/Other Sources</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" value="79" name="SourceFunds*SourceOfFundsYr1*SourceID^SourceNumber*1113^1"/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" value="0" name="SourceFunds*SourceOfFundsYr2*SourceID^SourceNumber*1113^1"/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" value="0" name="SourceFunds*SourceOfFundsYr3SourceID^SourceNumber*1113^1"/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Re: "type-in-the-box" functionality, do you mean like these combo boxes? http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx ?

Comment: I like the approach done here, it seems very easy and intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer seems to be the comment suggesting this link:
[demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/)

I have started a javascript file so I can generalize this concept, so it can fit in well with what I am doing.

I haven't used a framework for my selectors, ajax calls or event handling, no point getting one just for one component when I can write it myself.

This design seems very useful and I will use the canvas tag for the image of the downarrow.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

- Lay thing out so the box is wider, not tall. so you've got [select][textinput][+] (where that + is a button to commit the contents of the textinput]
- Have a magic selection in the select dropdown "Add New".  Selecting that option presents a modal window of some sort with a text-input and "add" button.  Clicking add adds the element to the select list's list of options, selects that option, and fires whatever your regular process is.
- Look around for a combobox library that does what you want.  It will probably emulate a  element, as opposed to actually using one.

Comment: I thought about the Add new option, but I like the popup idea, that I didn't consider.

Wider will be a problem as I want this to fit on smaller monitors if possible, without scrolling, though it is only 7 columns, the select box can be quite wide (30+ characters)

Comment: I included the "wider" option just for completeness.  It's a very lazy approach.

Bobince's answer contains links to some javascript combobox libraries of the sort I was talking about in my third point.

I think the modal "add new" form is probably the way to go.  It should be performant, obvious to users, and fairly easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that sounds highly confusing to me. Most users probably won't try typing a new entry as there is no visual affordance for it, and those that do will probably be trying to use the keyboard to select an existing entry!

How about something like a small button to the right of the select box which turns it into a writable until you press Enter or unfocus it? That would be clearer to me.

Or you could replace the whole select control with a JavaScript-controlled analogue on the fly. There are quite a few libraries that do this for you (eg. [1](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/form_widget_editable_select/form_widget_editable_select.html), [2](http://coffeescripter.com/code/editable-select/), [3](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jec/)); I've never found one that quite gets everything right (especially with the keyboard control), but one of these may be good enough.

Comment: Links `2` and `3` in answer seems dead.